# Temporary tables in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i have sql building a temporary table. it runs fine in SQL server management studio, but as soon as i put it into the crystal report add command feature it doesnt work. i have found that it is not working when it try and update the table with this line of code.

```
declare @newDate datetime
select @newDate = MIN(r.DateTimeStamp)
 from StationInspection as si
left outer join
    @report_out as r
on r.InspectionID = si.InspectionID
where r.Station = 2     


UPDATE @report_out 
 set
DateTimeStamp = @newDate
where Station = 2
```

i am just not sure why that made Crystal Reports not accpet it any long

Comment: Crystal Reports is a reporting tool, I would not expect to see any CRUD code to support a report and I'd bet (although I don't know as I don't use Crystal Reports) Crystal Reports doesn't either. I have never seen a report of any type that uses anything other than a SELECT as the report source.

Comment: @HLGEM that is what i decided (although not as technical as you said it). i am in process of rewriting my SQL to get the results i need

Answer (score 0):

You might try moving the update statement before the select statement to see if it will output data. I could be wrong, but I'd assume that the command is expecting an output of a table/select statement and it may be trying to output the results of the update statement (ie. "N Rows Affected"). Hope this helps.